# Angular - LocalStorageModule - Test

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

I'm tring to write a test for a Service that use the LocalStorageModule for Angular Js , i can add and use the Module in the service that i use but when i'm going to test a simple unit test i get this error :

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module LocalStorageModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'LocalStorageModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/nomod?p0=LocalStorageModule
```

here id how i try to write simple test :

```
'use strict';

describe('Service: AService', function () {

// load the service's module
beforeEach(module('testApp'));

// instantiate service
var AService;

// ---------------------------------- BeforeEach ------------------------------
beforeEach(inject(function (_AService_) {
 // inject the AService
 AService = _AService_;

}));

// ------------------------------------ Tests ---------------------------------
it('Should ..... ', function () {

  // expect(!!AService).toBe(true);
  expect(true).toBe(true);
 });

});
```

The module in the service (The Service Work great) :

```
angular.module('testApp')
.factory('AService', function (localStorageService) {
  return {
  a_method: function(){

    return = localStorageService.get('first_value');
   }
 });
```

In app.js i have the module injection :

```
 angular
   .module('testApp', [
       'ngResource',
       'ngRoute',
       'LocalStorageModule'
 ]) ...
```

karma.conf.js

```
  module.exports = function(config) {

config.set({
  // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
  autoWatch: true,

  // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
  basePath: '../',

  // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
  frameworks: ['jasmine'],

  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'app/scripts/**/*.js',
    'test/mock/**/*.js',
    'test/spec/**/*.js'
 ],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [],

// web server port
port: 8080,


browsers: [
  'PhantomJS'
],

// Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-jasmine'
],

singleRun: false,

colors: true,
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


 });
};
```

I think to have misunderstand how load the external module in the test scenario. thanks for help !

Comment: in your tests you are instantiating the `testApp` module, but you have `testApp` and `testAuthApp` in the actual code. Which is it?

Comment: Only Copy and Paste error ! I mean check if i made some errors in test file because only the test fail ...

Comment: Do you have the JS file defining LocalStorageModule in  the list of JS files to load (in the html test file, or in the karma configuration)?

Comment: JB can you make me an example ? I use Yeoman to scafolding and the karma config is (added to initial post ) !

Comment: Why don't you answer my question? Where is the JS file defining the module `LocalStorageModule`?

Comment: bower install angular-local-storage , all the files are in the /bower_components folder !

Comment: Do you see `bower_components/angularlocal-storage/the_name_of_the_file.js` in the `files` array of karma.conf.js? I don't. So karma doesn't load the JS file containing this module. So the module can't be found by Angular.

Answer (score 3):

OK Thanks  ... Solved !

I miss to link the module in the > karma.conf.js so the Module work in the Angular App but not under test ! I only need to add the right path to the angular-local-storage :

```
 // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [

'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
'bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',//< HERE
'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'

],
```